# Android permissions in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-service

I written 2 apps.

First app has only service and second one has an Activity. I am starting the service in 1st app from activity in 2nd app. In Service I am modifying audio settings so, I need `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` in manifest.

My question is **in which manifest file I have to add this permission**. Why I am asking because if I add this permission in Service app manifest I am getting warning **Exported service does not require permission**.

If anybody know it, post the solution.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com you mean I have to accept the answers even they are not solutions to my problems ??

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this permission to **application**, not service. Permissions for services are to let you limit who can access them which is something different. You need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

to your Manifest, above `<application>` block of application that does the audio settings change.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that added permission in Service. I told Service app manifest, that means to application only.

Comment: You said "Exported service does not require permission." which means you tried to add it in wrong place. Again, your **application** needs `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permissions. That one that does the change.